# How to pass get parameters with the same key twice in asp.net MVC RedirectToAction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction, grid.mvc

I'm developing a asp.net mvc website for an intranet system. In this system, I have several pages with grids. I am using the `Grid.MVC` extension to build these grids.

`Grid.MVC` supports the filter function based on `GET` parameters. For example, if I want to filter the column name where `name = "michael"`, I need to pass a url `GET` parameter like this: `?grid-filter=name__1__michael;`. The number 1 refers to the type of filter, equals in this case.

It supports multiple filters too. To use this, I need to pass the grid-filter parameter multiple times, like `?grid-filter=name__1__michael;grid-filter=age__1__21`. I don't know how to pass the grid filter multiple times when I am returning a redirectresult from an action. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Having searched awhile to solve the problem myself, plus if I understand you correctly, I think what you want to do is to PASS (multiple-times) SAME PARAMETER to controller.

Definitely as your questions states, it can help to redirect to the appropriate page while retaining all the data.

Here is a simple MVC example with Controller and View.

```
public ActionResult(List<string> gridfilter, List<string> param2)
{
  ViewBag.gridfilter = gridfilter;
  ViewBag.param2= param2;
}
```

Then, to display the values in View, you can do like this on the View Page:

```
@foreach(var grids in ViewBag.gridfilter)
{
  <p>@grids</> //displays current value 
}
@foreach(var param in ViewBag.param2)
{
  <p>@param</> //displays param 2 value
}
```

In your Url, you can then post as many value of your parameters as you want.

Example:`http://example.com?gridfilter=anystring&gridfilter=anystringagain&param2=anystring`